# Anyone use Zorin OS 9?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just tried to install ROS on my computer.
I am not totally new to Linux, but not a expert.
I tried installing and it did not work.

Any step by step instructions would be appreciated.

Thanks...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200319/anyone-use-zorin-os-9?/) by [tman67](https://answers.ros.org/users/21271/tman67/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Caveat: I have no idea whether the following will work, but it is worth a shot.

---

According to [distrowatch.com](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=zorin), Zorin OS 9 is based on Ubuntu. Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) to be precise, according to [this](http://zoringroup.com/blog/2014/07/15/zorin-os-9-core-and-ultimate-are-released/) post on their blog.

ROS Indigo can be installed on Ubuntu Trusty, but you'll have to help the ROS OS detector, since it doesn't know about Zorin OS. You could try to see whether setting [ROS_OS_OVERRIDE](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_OS_OVERRIDE) is enough. Add the following to the end of your `.bashrc` file (which is in your home directory):

```
export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=ubuntu:14.04
```

Then start a new terminal, and see if things start working.

PS: in the future, please add more information to your questions. We don't know which version of ROS you're trying to install, what kind of machine you have (32 or 64 bit), or even what "did not work". Simply stating that something didn't work is *not* sufficient. We don't have crystal balls ..

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0